# what means 耳障りのいい?

Tags: translation, meaning

This is a line of dialogue Psycho-pass movie:

> 何か耳障りのいい思想でも吹き込んでやったのか？

what means 耳障りのいい?
It's a bit contradictory, I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author has mixed 耳障り and 耳触り. 障 ("disturb") and 触 ("touch") are totally different kanji, although they may
look somewhat similar.

手【て】触【ざわ】り and 肌【はだ】触【ざわ】り safely mean "feel, touch (e.g., of a blanket)," and they are used with いい. We don't say 手障り.

> - 手触りがよい毛布
> - なめらかな肌触りのマフラー

As for 耳, both 耳【みみ】障【ざわ】り and 耳【みみ】触【ざわ】り exist. 耳障り means "annoying to the ear, noisy" and this is the traditional and normal meaning of みみざわり.

耳触り is used by some people in the same way as 手触り/肌触り. So it means "feel (of a sound/word)". This word is now listed in some dictionaries, but I have seen people who say 耳触り is confusing and thus should not be used. Personally, I tend to avoid using 耳触り, too.

Apparently, the author of this sentence was also confused and used 耳障り in the place where 耳触り is clearly the right choice of kanji. (IMEs usually show 耳障り first, because it's far more common)

See also [「耳ざわり」は「障り」か「触り」か - 文化部国語課](http://prmagazine.bunka.go.jp/rensai/kotoba/kotoba_004.html). This article even used BCCWJ Corpus and showed 耳障りがいい is a rather common misspelling.

> 二つの語の使い分けは十分に理解されているとは言えず，「聞いたときの感じ」の意味で用いる「耳ざわりが良い」といった表現に違和感を覚える人も少なからずいるようです。前述のように，辞書によっては，誤用としているものもありました。
>
> 今のところ，「聞いたときの感じ」の意味で「耳ざわり」を用いることには，慎重であった方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 1):

It means "sounds comfortable", "agreeable to the ear". It's a phrase.

However, there is an opinion that this is wrong, because 耳障り is used in a negative way.

Related: [http://www.weblio.jp/content/耳障りのいい](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%80%B3%E9%9A%9C%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E3%81%84%E3%81%84)